# Difference between value of first and last record Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have data in my List as below

```
profilename    date        score
prof1          01/10/2015  15
prof1          02/10/2015  15
prof1          03/10/2015  18
....
prof1          25/10/2015  24
prof2          01/10/2015  69
prof2          02/10/2015  70
prof3          01/10/2015  115
prof3          02/10/2015  115
prof2          03/10/2015  73
prof3          03/10/2015  119
....
prof2          25/10/2015  98
prof3          25/10/2015  187
```

I want to calculate the difference of score between the first and last record by date of each profilename. Required output is

```
prof1 9
prof2 29
prof3 72
```

I have no idea how to start out this query in Linq as I am new to it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the type of "date"? `string` or `DateTime'?

Comment: `string` datatype it is

Comment: "Downvoter", care to comment the reason for downvote?

Comment: on stackoverflow, you are expected to put a little effort in first, before asking the question. Show us the code so far - what have you tried?

Comment: Your expected output seems to be wrong for prof3 look at [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HCTelg) fiddle it needs to be 69 instead of 72.

Comment: What LINQ provider, Linq-To-Objects or database driven like Linq-To-Sql?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya thank you for pointing out, I modified the question accordingly

Comment: @TimSchmelter Linq-To-Sql prefereably

Comment: @buffjape i agree to your point, but as I have said in the question, I am new to Linq so din't knew about `First` and `Last` which I am seeing in the answers, hence did not start the query and did not post any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to calculate the difference of score between the first and last record by date of each profilename.

So you need to **group** by `profilename`, **sort** each group by `date`, take the first and last item and calculate the difference

```
var result =
    (from item in list
     group item by item.profilename into g
     let groupItems = g.OrderBy(gi => Convert.ToDateTime(gi.date))
     select new { profilename = g.Key, score = groupItems.Last().score - groupItems.First().score }
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `profilename` and calc difference like:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(c => c.profilename).
             Select(c => new 
                    { 
                       profilename = c.Key, 
                       score = c.FirstOrDefault(m => m.date == c.Max(v => v.date)).score - 
                               c.FirstOrDefault(m => m.date == c.Min(v => v.date)).score 
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's Linq-To-Sql as mentioned in the comment this is probably the best approach:

```
var result = profiles
        .GroupBy(p => p.profilename)
        .Select(g => new {
            profilename = g.Key,
            firstscore = g.OrderBy(p => p.date).First().score,
            lastscore = g.OrderByDescending(p => p.date).First().score
        })
        .Select(x => new { x.profilename, diff = x.lastscore - x.firstscore })
        .ToList();
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bJuXyk)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best performance, but if you care about performance just don't use LINQ

```
.GroupBy(e => e.Group).Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(e.Key, e.OrderBy(f => f.Date).Last().Num - e.OrderBy(f => f.Date).First().Num)).ToList();
```

Comment: Needs more line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (full code below, using `DateTime`):

```
var l = list.OrderBy(i => i.date)
            .GroupBy(i => i.profileName)
            .Select(e => new {prof = e.First().profileName, diff = e.Last().score - e.First().score}).ToList();
```

Here's a compilable example including your data:

```
class Rate
{
    public Rate(string p, string d, int s)
    {
        profileName = p;
        date = DateTime.Parse(d);
        score = s;
    }

    public string profileName;
    public DateTime date;
    public int score;
}

void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Rate>()
    { 
        new Rate("prof1", "01/10/2015", 15),
        new Rate("prof1", "02/10/2015", 15),
        new Rate("prof1", "03/10/2015", 18),

        new Rate("prof1", "25/10/2015", 24),
        new Rate("prof2", "01/10/2015", 69),
        new Rate("prof2", "02/10/2015", 70),
        new Rate("prof3", "01/10/2015", 115),
        new Rate("prof3", "02/10/2015", 115),
        new Rate("prof2", "03/10/2015", 73),
        new Rate("prof3", "03/10/2015", 119),

        new Rate("prof2", "25/10/2015", 98),
        new Rate("prof3", "25/10/2015", 184),
    };

    var l = list.OrderBy(i => i.date)
                .GroupBy(i => i.profileName)
                .Select(e => new {prof = e.First().profileName, diff = e.Last().score - e.First().score}).ToList();
}
```